# How to Show custom HTML template during dragging a Element?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

When we drag a element we see the ghost image of the element and we can change the image using this:

```
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(image, xOffset, yOffset);
```

But in my case I want to show a custom HTML template with some information.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use JqueryUI to achive this.

see **[this](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback)** and try to drag the last box on first row of example.

```
$( "#draggable3" ).draggable({
      cursor: "move",
      cursorAt: { top: -12, left: -20 },
      helper: function( event ) {
        return $( "<div class='ui-widget-header'>I'm a custom helper</div>" );
      }
    });
```

you can combine you can combine http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable with the one i gave you. Not so sure but yea if you do little bit of goggling then you can solve it.

```
    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({
          connectToSortable: "#sortable",          
          cursor: "move",
          cursorAt: { top: -12, left: -20 },
          helper: function( event ) {
            return $( "<div class='ui-widget-header'>I'm a custom helper</div>" );
          }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is not the drag & Drop. Its just changing the X & Y co-ordinate of the element. Using this i will never   be knowing on which element the dragged element is present.

Comment: My requirement is to sort the list by drag and drop.

Comment: How ? can you please give me some example of sorting using this?